# Crossfilter Grouping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I've just started getting to grips with Crossfilter (used with D3 and DC) and I'm running in to a problem trying to group data and output a chart based on that grouping. I have some data which records a date, a start and end time, and an activity. What I'm trying to acheive is a pie chart which will show the proportion of time spent on each activity, and a stacked bar chart which should break down the activities by day with the stack being composed of the time spent on each activity on a given day. Here is the code I have so far (with a small sample dataset):

```
var data = [
    {
      "starttime": 1470322800,
      "endtime": 1470330000,
      "activity": "Other",
      "capturedate": 1470268800
    },
    {
      "starttime": 1470391200,
      "endtime": 1470410400,
      "activity": "Photography",
      "capturedate": 1470355200
    },
    {
      "starttime": 1470411000,
      "endtime": 1470414600,
      "activity": "Admin",
      "capturedate": 1470355200
    },
];

function doTime(t){
    var d = moment.duration(t, 'seconds');
    var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
    var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
    goTime = hours + " Hours " + mins + " Mins";
    return goTime;
}

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.capturedate = new Date(d.capturedate * 1000);
    d.Day=d.metacapturedate.getDate();
    d.Month=d.metacapturedate.getMonth();
    d.Year=d.metacapturedate.getFullYear();

    var dur = d.endtime - d.starttime;
    d.duration = doTime(dur);
});


var activityLog = crossfilter(data);

var actDim = activityLog.dimension(function(d){return d.activity;});
var dayDim = activityLog.dimension(function(d){return +d.Day;});

var myPho = dayDim.group().reduceCount(function(d){if(d.activity == "School Photography"){return d.duration}else{return 0;}});
var myAdm = dayDim.group().reduceCount(function(d){if(d.activity == "Activity"){return d.duration}else{return 0;}});
var myOth = dayDim.group().reduceCount(function(d){if(d.activity == "Other"){return d.duration}else{return 0;}});
var countMeasure = actDim.group().reduceCount();

var actRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-act");
var actBarChart   = dc.barChart("#chart-bar-act");

actRingChart
    .width(320).height(320)
    .dimension(actDim)
    .group(countMeasure)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(110).y(120).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderLabel(false)
    .innerRadius(80);

// set up the bar chart
actBarChart
    .width(800).height(400)
    .dimension(dayDim)
    .group(myPho,"Photography")
    .stack(myAdm,"Admin")
    .stack(myOth,"Other")
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1,8]))
    .yAxisLabel("Time Spent Per Day");

// render all charts
dc.renderAll();
```

This is giving me a pie chart showing the proportion of the number of times an activity has been carried out (rather than a proportion of time spent) and a bar chart which similarly shows a count of activities rather than a duration. I'm still a bit hazy on how grouping and map-reduce stuff works in Crossfilter, so I'm unclear on how to interogate the data properly. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be very gratefully received.

(I'm also using Moment.js to handle the date/time format stuff, but not having any issues with doing that).

Thanks

Comment: Use reduceSum instead of reduceCount. reduceCount just counts the number of records and doesn't take an argument at all. reduceSum adds up the value returned by the function passed as its argument. It looks to me like this should work if you just switch to reduceSum.

Comment: At your suggestion I tried substituting reduceSum for reduceCount, but, while the pie chart remains unaffected, the bar chart now doesn't show anything at all. Help!

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you are currently using. If you can put together a working example on JSFiddle or the like, that would be ideal, but at the least we need to be able to see the code that is breaking.

Comment: I began trying to put together a Jsfiddle with the working code as far as I'd got it. During this I found I had to eliminate the moment.js stuff as I couldn't find a source to use it as an external resource in the fiddle. In doing this I realized that the d.duration being returned is not a number, but a string ( e.g. 2 Hours 34 Mins). As soon as d.duration started returning just a number it all fell in to place! Your initial steer put me on the right course, but my own oversight was preventing your answer from working. Cheers!